# unable to access HTML Select Option using selenium getting error. ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to scrape data from this [File-tuning](https://file-tuning.com/chiptuning) dynamic website which is loading data through javascript (ajax) requests.

what is want to do is that It selects cars from type and then selects make, model, engine iteratively, and then I want to scrape data for each make, model, and engine.

**Here is the code I write to select cars from type**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

PATH = "C:\SeleniumDrivers\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=PATH)

driver.get("https://file-tuning.com/chiptuning")

type_element_select = driver.find_element_by_id("type")
action = ActionChains(driver) 
action.move_to_element(type_element_select)
action.click(type_element_select)
action.perform()
action.move_to_element(Select(type_element_select).select_by_value("cars"))
action.click(Select(type_element_select).select_by_value("cars"))
action.perform()
```

**The error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\selenium\test.py", line 27, in <module>
    action.move_to_element(Select(type_element_select).select_by_value("cars"))
  File "C:\Users\Umair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 82, in select_by_value
    self._setSelected(opt)
  File "C:\Users\Umair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 212, in _setSelected
    option.click()
  File "C:\Users\Umair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Umair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Umair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

**I also try this**

```
types_element = driver.find_element_by_id("type")
types_object = Select(types_element)
types_object.select_by_visible_text("Cars")
```

but it also gives me the same exception.
how I can scrape through this site?
already have seen and tried other StackOverflow related question but didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use browser in full screen mode :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

so that all web elements would be visible to Selenium.

**Sample code :**

```
PATH = "C:\SeleniumDrivers\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=PATH)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://file-tuning.com/chiptuning")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

type_element_select = driver.find_element_by_id("type")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(type_element_select)
action.click(type_element_select)
action.perform()
action.move_to_element(Select(type_element_select).select_by_value("cars"))
action.click(Select(type_element_select).select_by_value("cars"))
action.perform()
```